# Difference between doing a Software reset via NVIC and RCC Software Reset Flag

Tags: embedded, stm32

I'm working on a Project in which, if I plug in a device, the MCU(STM32G0) should perform a software reset. I do not know which way I should choose, to achieve the software reset.
Should I simply call the NVIC System Reset or should I use the Software Reset Bit in the Reset and Control Register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What RCC "Software Reset Flag" are you referring to?  The RCC has a flag to indicate that a software reset occurred, it does not have a *control* bit to effect a reset. A *flag* is *by definition* an indicator not a *control*.

From the reference manual section 5.1.2:

> *Software reset*
>
> The SYSRESETREQ bit in Cortex®-M0+ Application interrupt and reset control register
> must be set to force a software reset on the device (refer to the programming manual
> PM0223).

So the answer is clear, there is only one method defined.

Even if the RCC had that ability, or you used some other method such as forcing a watchdog expiry, the NVIC (and specifically SYSRESETREQ) are common across ARM devices from multiple vendors, so it would in any event be the common/portable method.